# The field is present in page layout but it is not showing to the Admin

Tags: fields, admin

The field is present in page layout but it is not showing to the Admin. Upon saving the record the following error is showing. Admin has read and edit permission for this. Can you please help?

[image]

Comment: Check the FLS (Field-Level Security) for the field. FLS is not deployed alongside fields if the field was created in one org and then deployed to another org.

Comment: you check the field level security for admin profile for the particular field and also check the respective page layout assigned to admin profile or not.